# Active Record set_table_name error for .sqlite file

Tags: ruby, sqlite, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to interact with a .sqlite file by connecting to it with Active Record. I'm doing this:

```
require 'active_record'

# Connect to DB
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection( :adapter => 'sqlite3', :database => 'database.sqlite')

# Log the tables to make sure Active Record is connected to the DB correclty
puts ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables

# Map from existing table records to a Active Record model
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "ZPATIENT"
end
```

The connection to the database works as printing out the database tables gives:

```
ZPATIENT
ZZCONFIG
Z_PRIMARYKEY
Z_METADATA
```

But the attempt to map `ZPATIENT` table to Patient Active Record models fails with:

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing': undefined method `set_table_name' for Patient(Table doesn't exist):Class (NoMethodError)
    from script.rb:8:in `<class:Patient>'
    from script.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong? Do I need to do some sort of migration for Active Record to understand how to map the table to models?

Comment: Maybe it's silly, but have you tried `self.table_name` instead of `set_table_name` ??

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`set_table_name` was removed. Try with:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'ZPATIENT'
end
```

Comment: I'm think going to regret giving him the answer in the comment :P

Comment: Thanks that worked great. Thanks also to @NicoSantangelo, sorry I can't accept your comment

Comment: @NicoSantangelo I have the same error as described above but I don't have set_table_name in any of my code.

Comment: Thank you. This is nice answer, it help to solve my job easily.